# How to keep the same font and color when we do a carriage return in Pycharm with Robot Framework?

Tags: pycharm, robotframework

I don't manage to keep the same font and color while doing a carriage return in Robotframework.

If you look at this screenshot, you'll see "This is my test case." in the right font and color but not "This is my test case again" below.

Someone knows how to fix this ? Using the carriage return is more convenient if the Documentation is long.

[image]

Comment: What is "This is my test case." - part of the case's documentation, or a keyword call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pycharm is alerting you to the fact that `This is my test case again` is a test step. It is not part of the documentation. That is why it appears in the same color as a keyword rather than the same color of the documentation.

If you want `this is my test case again` to be part of the documentation, you need to use robot's continuation characters. See [Dividing test data to several rows](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#dividing-test-data-to-several-rows) in the robot framework user guide.

```
My test case
    [Documentation]  This is my test case.
    ...  This is my test case again
```